# scope of a global variable in drupal module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, global-variables

What is the scope of a 'global' variable inside a module in Drupal?  I created a module for a custom block and need to know how long the global stays set for so I know how to use them.  Do they stay across the website instance, or only once for the page.  For example in the following code `drupal_set_message` gets called once every time I load a page with the block.  Can I be sure the 'global' variable is refreshed each time the block is loaded?

```
<?php

global $my_array;

function fill_array()
{
  global $my_array;
  if(!isset($my_array))
  {
    drupal_set_message("filling the array");
    $my_array = array();
    // code to fill array up...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out what documentation says:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Global variables are by default available to all global code. But if you want to use them inside you function you have to declare them as global first.

And any kind php variable has lifetime no longer then one "page call". So with your next page call all the values are lost.

If you want to keep some value longer than single execution you must use php sessions or cookie or file or database....to store them there.

Comment: got it--I was thinking about the session wide global variables like `$user` but I guess those are different.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but scope is more tricky than this.

Drupal executes a block of PHP in a function context using eval() so variables defined at the top level within your PHP code are not in the global context unless they are explicitly set as global.

In other words, your code has three contexts, not the normal two.